# null pointer exception when adding to HashSet

Tags: java, jpa, nullpointerexception, ejb, hashset

Even though I have initialized the HashSet, I get a null pointer exception when I try to add an element to it.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "artikal")
private Set<Cenovnik> cene = new HashSet<Cenovnik>();

public Set<Cenovnik> getCene() {
    if (cene == null)
        this.cene = new HashSet<Cenovnik>();

    return cene;
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
Cenovnik cenovnik = new Cenovnik(date, null, cena);
Artikal artikal = artikalDao.findById(id);
Cenovnik stari = artikalDao.cena(id);

if (stari != null) {
    stari.setKrajkVazenja(date);
    cenovnikDao.merge(stari);
}

cenovnik.setArtikal(artikal);
artikal.getCene().add(cenovnik); //error!
cenovnikDao.persist(cenovnik);
artikalDao.merge(artikal);
```

So, the error occurs when I try to add cenovnik to artikal.getCene, I have already checked, for some reason getCene seems to be the problem.
Here is the Cenovnik class

```
public class Cenovnik implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1436274372349853081L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "cenovnik_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
  ...   

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="artikal_id", referencedColumnName="artikal_id")
private Artikal artikal;    

public Artikal getArtikal() {
    return artikal;
}

public void setArtikal(Artikal artikal) {
    this.artikal = artikal;
}
    ...
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

}
Here is the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:

        rs.ac.uns.acs.ism.server.servlet.DodajCenuArtiklaController.doGet(DodajCenuArtiklaController.java:78)

        rs.ac.uns.acs.ism.server.servlet.DodajCenuArtiklaController.doPost(DodajCenuArtiklaController.java:109)

        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)

        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)

        rs.ac.uns.acs.ism.server.servlet.DodajArtikalController.doGet(DodajArtikalController.java:72)

        rs.ac.uns.acs.ism.server.servlet.DodajArtikalController.doPost(DodajArtikalController.java:94)

        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)

        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)

        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)

        org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)

        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)

        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)

        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)

        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)

        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)

        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)

        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)

        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)

        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)

        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and here is equals method:

```
    @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Cenovnik other = (Cenovnik) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you post code of Cenovnik class

Comment: You get an exception *where*? Post the stack trace and identify lines.

Comment: NPE in *your own* code?

Answer (score 1):

**if artikal is null that is a separate case. then do a null check like this**

```
 if(artikal != null) {
    artikal.getCene().add(cenovnik);
 }
```

Try this to debug break up the getCene() and add into two line and add some print statements of if you are using some logger use that. This will help know what's going on

```
       if(artikal != null) {
            System.out.println("artikal is not null");
            Set<Cenovnik> cenovniks= artikal.getCene();

            if(cenovniks != null) {
                System.out.println("cenovniks set is not null");
                cenovniks.add(cenovnik);
                System.out.println("Added cenovnik to set");
            } else {
                // Handle null cenovniks as appropriate to your application
                System.out.println("cenovniks set is null");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("artikal is null");
            // Handle null artikal as appropriate to your application
        }
```

**Otherwise**

**PLEAS NOTE this applies only to add() method of hashset when adding to hashset**

One reason adding a object to a set can throw a null pointer exception is:

One of the properties of the object that is being added to hashset is used in calculation of hashcode of the object. And during calculation hashcode this property is throwing a null pointer exception.

It can be date or some other property. Check hashcode implementation of the class put a break point in hashcode method  to see if that throwing this nullpointer.

**Update 1**
Looking at the hascode and equals methods seems like they are not causing the problem.

Comment: One thing I notice although unrelated in your equals method you are not checking if Cenovnik other = (Cenovnik) obj; the object passed in of type Cenovnik. This may blow up.

Comment: artikal.getCene().add(cenovnik); - i have mark it as error

Comment: @user3638849 Try the latest snippet this will give some more info what's going on. Also whosoever down voted please leave a comment why you downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a record from a datasource and then using it without checking to see if it is null.

try

```
Artikal artikal = artikalDao.findById(id);

if (artikal != null) {
   artikal.getCene().add(cenovnik);
}  else 
{
   // throw something
}
```